# Find the last remaining vertex of n-sided polygon after deleting n-1 vertices

Tags: list, algorithm

**Problem Description:**
Considering we have an n-sided polygon. It has vertices numbered 1 to n in a clockwise fashion. 
We start at any vertex, let's say 1, we must delete the vertex, and move to the next vertex.
The next vertex must always be 2 vertices away from the current vertex and must be reached in a clockwise direction. That is after deleting vertex number 1, the next vertex I would visit is 3, which is two vertices away from 1 clockwise.

**Objective**:- Perform deletions in the way mentioned above, until left with only one vertex.

**Example**: If I have a 5 sided polygon with vertices 1,2,3,4 and 5. I start at vertex 3, delete the vertex. I move two vertices away from it to vertex 5, delete it, then move to vertex 2, delete it, then to vertex 1 (2 and 3 are already deleted) delete it and finally I am left with vertex 4.

**Code**:

```
    n=5
    start_vertex=2 #Vertices are considered 0 indexed for the sake of modulo operation
    vert_status=[]
    deletionCount=0
    while(deletionCount<n-1):
        vert_status.append(start_vertex)
        next_vertex=start_vertex
        count=0
        while(count!=2):
            next_vertex=(next_vertex+1)%n
            if(next_vertex not in vert_status):
                count+=1            
        start_vertex=next_vertex
        explosionCount+=1

    print("End",start_vertex+1)
```

**Code Explanation:**
The above is my attempt. I am actually running a while loop, and adding the deleted vertices into a list, then navigating to the next by checking my list to see if it has not already been deleted. The while loop executes until n-1 vertices have been deleted.

**Problem with my current approach and what I think might be the road to a better solution:**
While it is correct, my code does not do well for extremely large sided polygons. So I couldn't help but wonder if there is some simple relationship between the start and end vertices given the value 'n' and the condition that the next vertex is 2 vertices away from the current.

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to note is that a shift in your starting position produces that same shift in your ending position, since it's no different than just rotating all the vertices by that amount.  So, we can focus on solving the case where you start at vertex number 1 (for every `n`), just keeping in mind that you'll have to apply the appropriate shift to to get each of the other solutions.

Another thing to note is that starting at 1 we first hit all the odd numbers (since we're incrementing by 2 each time).  On the next pass, we're effectively incrementing by 4 (since we're incrementing by 2 but with half the numbers removed), and on the next pass after that we're effectively incrementing by 8, and on the pass after that we're effectively incrementing by 16, etc.

This gives rise to a noticeable pattern:

```
n =  3:  result =  2; sequence = 1, 3, 2
n =  4:  result =  4; sequence = 1, 3, 2, 4
n =  5:  result =  2; sequence = 1, 3, 5, 4, 2
n =  6:  result =  4; sequence = 1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 4
n =  7:  result =  6; sequence = 1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 2, 6
n =  8:  result =  8; sequence = 1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 6, 4, 8
n =  9:  result =  2; sequence = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 4, 8, 6, 2
n = 10:  result =  4; sequence = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 6,10, 8, 4
n = 11:  result =  6; sequence = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9,11, 4, 8, 2,10, 6
n = 12:  result =  8; sequence = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9,11, 2, 6,10, 4,12, 8
n = 13:  result = 10; sequence = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9,11,13, 4, 8,12, 6, 2,10
n = 14:  result = 12; sequence = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9,11,13, 2, 6,10,14, 8, 4,12
n = 15:  result = 14; sequence = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9,11,13,15, 4, 8,12, 2,10, 6,14
n = 16:  result = 16; sequence = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9,11,13,15, 2, 6,10,14, 4,12, 8,16
n = 17:  result =  2; sequence = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9,11,13,15,17, 4, 8,12,16, 6,14,10, 2
n = 18:  result =  4; sequence = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9,11,13,15,17, 2, 6,10,14,18, 8,16,12, 4
n = 19:  result =  6; sequence = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9,11,13,15,17,19, 4, 8,12,16, 2,10,18,14, 6
n = 20:  result =  8; sequence = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9,11,13,15,17,19, 2, 6,10,14,18, 4,12,16,20, 8
```

Evidently the results are increasing even numbers counting up to a power of 2, then resetting and counting up to the next power of 2, etc.  (If I had included `n=1` and `n=2`, which aren't actually polygons, you'd get `2^0` and `2^1` as the first two solutions.)

A proof that this holds for all `n` is left "as an exercise for the reader", as textbook authors love to say. :)

Comment: `n = 1` is kind of an odd-ball case, since you don't get to delete anything. We could also interpret it as "we delete vertex 1, and then there is no solution."  I was on the fence about whether to mention that case at all.  But `n=2` fits the pattern of the subsequent cases.